# Getting started with android development on eclipse pulsar

Tags: android

I am just starting to get setup for android development. I have installed pulsar and the proper sdks I think. I want to develop for the droid x.

I can't find any information on how to create a new project using the installed sdks. Shouldn't there be a project type for android? Nothing like this is showing up.

Are there any tutorials for getting started using pulsar for android dev?

Comment: i am also looking for the same..

Answer (score 1):

Pulsar doesn't currently integrate with Android so just look for a tutorial that uses normal Eclipse

Comment: I think that this is a perfectly valid answer

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has been the default platform for the Android development kit for a number of years and you can still use it to develop for Android, but as Casbash points out, you do not need pulsar, you need the Android Development Kit for eclipse.

Note however that Android has officially moved over to the Android Studio which is based on intellij. If you are just starting I highly suggest you start there unless there is some reason to remain on Eclipse.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html